# Error al codificar letra Ñ en base64 con visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6, base64

Tengo una cadena que contiene el contenido de un XML y al intentar codificarlo a Base64 con la letra Ñ me genera un código incorrecto.

Asi lo mando a llamar:

```
X = Replace(Base64Encode(StrConv("Año", vbFromUnicode)), Chr(13), "")
```

y Esta es la función Base64Encode:

```
Function Base64Encode(Data() As Byte) As String
  Dim s As Long
  s = UBound(Data) + 1

  Dim ret() As Byte
  Dim retlen As Long
  Call CryptBinaryToStringA(VarPtr(Data(0)), s, 1073741825, StrPtr(ret), retlen)
  If retlen = 0 Then Exit Function

  'MsgBox retlen
  ReDim ret(retlen - 1)
  Call CryptBinaryToStringA(VarPtr(Data(0)), s, 1073741825, VarPtr(ret(0)), retlen)
  Base64Encode = StrConv(LeftB(ret, retlen), vbUnicode)
End Function
```

Esto utiliza la librería crypt32.dll:

```
Private Declare Function CryptBinaryToStringA Lib "crypt32.dll" (ByVal pbBinary As Long, ByVal cbBinary As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal pszString As Long, ByRef pcchString As Long) As Long
```

Comment: Probaste colocando vbUnicode en vez de vbFromUnicode; o por tro lado colocando vbFromUnicode dentro de la función Base64Encode ?????

Comment: Ya. Hace exatamente lo mismo pero con mas caracteres.  A�������o���